# Javascript - get object from an array, whose array matches another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (`zoo`) inside of which are some objects, and the objects have an array of objects (`animals`) in them. I need to filter the array, and get the objects with the same animal names, as another dynamic array in my code.

```
zoo

  0:[...]
  1:[...]
  2:
    name:"whatevername"
    city:"whatevercity"
    animals:Array(2)
        0:
          name:"somename"
          species:"somespecies"
        1: ...
    etc:"whasover"
```

So if my dynamic array contains `somename` in it, I should get the object with index 2. How do I go about something like that?

Comment: You go about it by writing as much as you can until you get to a point where you just don't know what to do. You then research that problem diligently. If after a good bit of research, you still can't figure it out, ask a question, present what you've written so far, and describe the part you can't figure out.

Comment: Object dot notation and the array filter method will be your friends here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function you need:

```js
const search = keyword => zoos.find(({ animals }) => animals.some(({ name }) => name == keyword));
```

Here's a live example:

```js
const zoos = [
  {
    name: 'Antarctic Zoo',
    city: 'Chilean Villa Las Estrellas',
    animals: [{ name: 'Chinstrap penguin', species: 'Pygoscelis antarctica' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'African Zoo',
    city: 'Cairo',
    animals: [{ name: 'Lion', species: 'Panthera leo' }],
  }
];

const search = keyword => zoos.find(({ animals }) => animals.some(({ name }) => name == keyword));

const result = search('Lion');

console.log(result); // { name: 'African Zoo', city: 'Cairo', animals: [ { name: 'Lion', species: 'Panthera leo' } ] }
```

Comment: That works beautifully, I was getting so lost. Is there a way to make this return multiple objects, if or examples two zoos have Lions?

Comment: Change `find` to `filter`.